# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vector-tiles

I have tried to implement the onClick event using this [vectorGrid plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) as below,

```js
const vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(street, {
    rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
    maxNativeZoom: 19,
    maxZoom: 20,
    interactive: true,
    getFeatureId: function (f) {
      return f.properties.name;
    },
  })
  .on("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

When I clicked the layer, it shows the following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
    at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:28)
    at i.project (Map.js:993)
    at i.latLngToLayerPoint (Map.js:1015)
    at i.latLngToContainerPoint (Map.js:1072)
    at i._fireDOMEvent (Map.js:1434)
    at i._handleDOMEvent (Map.js:1397)
    at HTMLDivElement.c (DomEvent.js:92)
```

In this error log, I didn't find the error linked to my vector grid file. Please help me how can I solve this issue?

Link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamtekson/a6s4qj8p/6/

**Note:** I have tried this plugin on these leaflet versions (1.0.0 to 1.2.0) which are working fine. But with the latest leaflet version, the plugin is out of date.

Comment: I'd watch [this bug report](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/148) if you're not already.

Comment: I am the one who added the bug there. But I expect a fast response here, that's why I have posted the question here as well.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link to an existing bug. It's unlikely you'll get an answer here since the problem is within that library

Comment: Voting to close as it's an existing bug in the Leaflet lib. Follow this issue ~ https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/148

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to the bug. Can you help me to solve the bug or any possible alternatives?

Comment: If you create jsfiddle maybe we can help you to find a solution. By the way, you are not creating a other Leaflet layer, correct? Because the same error happens if you create a `L.circle` with wrong coords

Comment: There's literally a solution in that issue I linked

Comment: I just added the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/iamtekson/a6s4qj8p/6/, any help please